# HY104 Sql server error when binding an empty string to a pdo prepared query

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sql-server-2000

I'm supposed to move an app from mssql functions to PDO. Everything was running smoothly until I found myself a nice little bug I can't seem to workaround.

Here is my prepared request :

```
$req_action="INSERT INTO [".DB_SCHEMA."].[dbo].[".ACTION_TABLE."] 
([ID_CONTACT]
,[ID_ADN]
,[TYPE_ACTION]
,[MOTIF_ENTRANT]
,[COMMENTAIRES_APPEL]
,[CODE_CAMPAGNE]
,[EMAIL]
,[SUJET]
,[STATUT_EMAILING]
,[DATE_ENVOI]
,[DELAI_OUVERTURE]
,[MAIL_CLIENT]
,[DATE_OUVERTURE]
,[LIEN_CLIQUE]
,[DELAI_CLIC]
,[DATE_CLIC]
,[DATE_ACTION]
,[USER_ID]
,[LOGIN]
,[DATE_CHARGEMENT]
)
VALUES
(''
,''
,'e-mailing'
,''
,''
,''
,:email
,:sujet
,:statut
,convert(datetime,:date_envoi,103)
,:delai
,:mail
,convert(datetime,:date_ouverture,103)
,:lien_clic
,:delai_clic
,convert(datetime,:date_clic,103)
,convert(datetime,:date_action,103)
,'1'
,'AUTO'
,getdate()
)";
```

and my bindings :

```
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":email",$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":sujet",$sujet,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":statut",$statut_emailing,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":date_envoi",$sql_date_envoi,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":delai",$delai_ouverture,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":mail",$mail_client,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":date_ouverture",$sql_date_ouverture,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":lien_clic",$lien_clique,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":delai_clic",$delai_clic,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":date_clic",$sql_date_clic,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep_req_action->bindValue(":date_action",$sql_date_action,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The issue is whenever one of my PHP variable happens to be an empty string (coming from an automated csv file it happens actually a lot) SQL server returns an error HY104 (Invalid precision).

All my fields are NULL authorized so I switched the `PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS` attribute to `PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING` to convert empty strings to NULL but behavior is exactly the same.

The only workaround I found is to test if my variable is empty to set it to php null before binding it:

```
$lien_clique = (empty($lien_clique)) ? null : $lien_clique;
```

This actually works but I feel like PDO attribute to NULL_EMPTY_STRING should do it for me and I have tons of query to update and I don't want to protect everything with this tweek.

Does anyone have any idea on the why of the problem and the how of the solution ?

FYI : PHP 5.3.1 on Linux, pdo_sqlsrv 3.0 and SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I know this is old, but have you tried doing: $prep_req_action->bindValue(":email",trim($email),PDO::PARAM_STR); to ensure there are no whitespace chars confusing things.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the idea. Unfortunately no I didn't think of triming the variables before binding. I actually protected all my bindings with the tweak I mentionned. But when I moved my app from dev platform to the production one the problem disapeared. I didn't have time to find out the configuration difference between those two environments.
My bet would be a version compatibility glitch on my dev environment setup.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a size set on the string column and your database probably requires that it gets specified at the time of insertion.

Try using...

```
$stmt->bindValue(":field",$value,PDO::PARAM_STR,$length);
```

On the field that gives you the error, where $length is the size of the field as specified in your database. It's a pain having to do this, but I remember running into this issue with the ODBC driver a while back.